# Can anybody recognize this cardiac waveform?

Tags: cardiology, electrocardiography, signal-processing

Is this an artifact or an arrhythmia?

[image]

Comment: What animal is this recording from? What is the nature of the recording? Where was the electrode placed? Did the animal move during the recording? Etc. I think we need more information.

Comment: There is also a [Medical Science Stack Exchange](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) site, I think that after you collect more information to address the questions in the comment above, you might consider asking there. But be sure to supply a lot more information than this.

Answer (score 0):

To be conclusive, another couple of leads recorded at the same time as this event would be helpful though the fact that you do have a recognisable QRS complex and a T wave and that the QRS happens before you would expect it to based on the prior rhythm and the P wave, if that is one, prior to it is to close to the QRS complex to have caused it would suggest a premature supraventricular arrhythmia.  There are many technical texts to consult to refine this further, if this is a small animal ECG, I recommend Larry Tilley's textbook entitled ECG for the small animal practitioner.